# Как сделать выдвигающееся меню?

Tags: css3, html

Помогите, кто может, заказчик попросил сделать выдвигающееся меню, а как его сделать, для меня тайна

[image]

Comment: Люди изобрели [яндекс.поиск][1] и [google.поиск][2]


  [1]: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E&clid=139040&yasoft=chrome&lr=20674
  [2]: https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Условно** идея такова:

```
<ul class="меню">
   <li class="подпункт">
      содержимое подпункта
      <div class="всплывающее-меню">
         содержимое всплывающего меню
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>

<style>
   .подпункт{
      position:relative;
   }
   .всплывающее-меню{
      position:absolute;
      display:none;
      top:высота-пункта-меню;
   }
   .подпункт:hover{
      display:block;
   }
</style>
```